# deleting an object from array in mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongo schema like this.

```
{
 userID:19202,
 products:[ { id:020, name:'first'  }]
}
```

I want to pop items from the product array based on id. I used the following command. although it didn't give any error, it also not deleting elements from an array.

```
 userCart.updateOne(
                { userID:userID},
                { $pull: { products: { id:id } } }
              )
             .then((data) =>
             {
                 if(data)
                 {

 //data is {
        "n": 1,
        "nModified": 0,
        "ok": 1
    }
                     return res.json({
                         status:true,
                         message:"cart updated"
                     })
                 }
             })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mh6fXN21vyR

Make sure `id` and `products.id` are of the same type as in your document in the database. As your sample, both should be numbers.

if they both are number

```
db.collection.update({
  userID: 19202
},
{
  $pull: {
    "products": { id: 20 }
  }
})
```

Not Working here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/3zhv8yoH2o9 when `"products": { id: "20" }`. `products.id` is a string in the mongo query and in the database in number so mismatched.

Comment: id and product.id is of string type

Comment: @Pranaykumar in that case make sure you are passing the strings in the update query not numbers from node.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.userCart.update(
  { userID:userID }, 
  { $pull: { items: { id: 020 } } },
  false, // Upsert
  true, // Multi
);
```